How to smooth a mesh out and solidify the object?
I'm trying to model a bike part. I modeled it by using the Displace Modifier with an image as a reference, but I'm stuck on smoothing the curves and solidifying the object for 3D printing. If I increase the number of cuts, my computer freezes.
Edit 2: I've managed to carve out the object. I have the bike part next to me and it's sufficient for my purposes to only extract the right highlighted part and soldify it as one object for 3d printing.




Hello and welcome. How did you model this? I don't think this will be usable, you most likely have to remodel this with proper topology.

Hello I modeled it by using the displace modifier and using the image as reference.

Have you seen the answer of TheLabCat? That is the way to go. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/320810/142292

I’m trying to tell you, this will not work. Can you not see that the shape you’ve produced in Blender is not the shape in the image, but a flattened version of it from an angle? The part you’ve selected happens to be the most parallel with the camera, so it is closer to the original than anything else, but it will only be flattened approximation of the real curve shape at best. Please, stop. This is equivalent to cutting out Mona Lisa from the painting in order to have a statue of her.

The method you are using will not accurately three dimensionally reproduce the object in the image. It is instead creating a surface that is thicker where the image is brighter. To recreate the object, you need something quite different. The cheapest option for you is to take photos from exact positions/angles, import those into Blender, and model it by hand to match them. The easier option is to 3-D scan the part, but that requires a scanner.
As for “smoothing the mesh out and solidifying the object,” I believe you want to look into remeshing and making your object manifold, but I don’t want to explain them with your current status being so off the target.

The part is symmetrical so I only need one half which can copied and flipped. Is there a 3d printing app that does the trick as well?

@user191781 Turning an angled photo like this into a 3-D object is something Nvidia themselves still have not mastered as I understand it. It was big when they were able to make even very blobby cars from a photo automatically just a few years ago.
